# Is there an equation for the cutoff frequency of a chebyshev filter?

Tags: filter, low-pass, cutoff-frequency

I have this circuit here which is a low pass chebyshev filter, I have been asked to find it's cutoff frequency. I have used matlab to plot an output response against angular frequency graph [here](https://gyazo.com/21f4e1202de35cee100379df2264e112). But I'm unsure of how to find the cut off frequency from this, is there an equation to do this?
[image]

Comment: Do you know the exact value of the passband ripple? (This will help in finding the cut-off frequency).

Comment: How are you sure that's a Chebyshev??

Comment: I believe the curve that has been plotted matches the shape of a Chebyshev. Also I don't know the passband ripple, is there a way of calculating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of the cut-off frequency of a [(type I) Chebyshev filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter#Type_I_Chebyshev_filters) is shown in the figure below:

[image]

> The common practice of defining the cutoff frequency at −3 dB is usually not applied to Chebyshev filters; instead the cutoff is taken as the point at which the gain falls to the value of the ripple for the final time.

Knowing the characteristics of a Chebyshev filter helps in computing the cut-off frequency (as defined above) *without* explicitly solving the equation \$|H(j\omega_0)|=c\$, where the constant \$c\$ is chosen according to the definition of the cut-off frequency.

The squared magnitude of the frequency response of an \$n^{th}\$ order type I Chebyshev filter is given by

$$|H(j\omega)|^2=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon^2T^2_n(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0})}\tag{1}$$

where \$T_n(\omega)\$ is the \$n^{th}\$-order [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind), \$\omega_0\$ is the cut-off frequency as defined above, and the constant \$\epsilon\$ specifies the pass band ripple, as shown in above figure. You should know the exact value of \$\epsilon\$ from your design specifications, but I can estimate it from your figure: \$\epsilon\approx 0.23403\$ (note that you need to take into account that the maximum of your transfer function is \$\frac12\$ instead of \$1\$, so the smallest (linear) pass band value is given by \$0.5/\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}\$).

In order to find \$\omega_0\$ we need to compare the expression for the actual transfer function to the one given by (1). It's a basic exercise to show that the transfer function of your filter is

$$H(s)=\frac{\frac12}{\frac{L^2C}{2R}s^3+LCs^2+(\frac{L}{R}+\frac{RC}{2})s+1}\tag{2}$$

[Knowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind) that \$T_3(x)\$ is given by

$$T_3(x)=4x^3-3x\tag{3}$$

we can compare the factors of the highest power of \$\omega\$ (which is \$\omega^6\$) of the denominators of (1) and of the squared magnitude of (2) for \$s=j\omega\$:

$$\frac{16\epsilon^2}{\omega_0^6}=\left(\frac{L^2C}{2R}\right)^2\tag{4}$$

From (4) \$\omega_0\$ can be expressed as

$$\omega_0=\sqrt[3]{\frac{8R\epsilon}{L^2C}}\approx 3829.7\text{ rad/s}\tag{5}$$

where I've used the approximate value of \$\epsilon\$ given above.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter *how* the filter was designed. Once you have a specific design, you write down the equation for its frequency response, and solve for the frequency at which that response drops to half power (-3 dB), which is the definition of cutoff frequency.

Matlab is very good at finding the roots of polynomial equations.

If you don't need a lot of precision, just read the value off the graph. Since the peak voltage response is 0.5, look for the point at which the curve crosses the 0.35 level (0.5/√2), which is just shy of 5000 rad/s.

Comment: Thank you very much! unfortunately I do need high accuracy. So I will be needing to calculate the frequency response. The input is just sin(wt) how would I form an equation for it's frequency response?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you need to show us what you do understand about the circuit and how to analyze it, and what specific point you're stuck on. The Q and A format used here is not suitable for providing you a complete education in circuit analysis. It should have been covered before you were given this problem.

Comment: yes homework question, and everything I have been given is in this post. Sorry I can't be of anymore help on this. Thanks for the advice

Comment: This is not how the cut-off frequency is generally defined for Chebyshev filters: "the cutoff is taken as the point at which the gain falls to the value of the ripple for the final time" (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter#Type_I_Chebyshev_filters)).

Comment: @MattL.: OK, but the same techniques are used either way.

Comment: @MattL. that isn't 100% true - if the passband ripple is less than 3 dB then the proper 3 dB point is chosen. If pass band ripple is greater than 3 dB then you choose the final excusion point as the pass band definition. Most designs I've ever done focus on low ripple hence a real 3 dB point definition.

Comment: @Andyaka: "if the passband ripple is less than 3 dB then the proper 3 dB point is chosen" Do you have a reference for that? BTW, less than 3 dB here usually means a *smaller ripple*, e.g. 1dB, just in case this was a misunderstanding.

Comment: @ohkneel, with crappy tolerances on caps and inductors, the best accuracy you'll get is by measuring.

Comment: So I just took 20log(Vout/Vin) and plotted this against angular frequency to produce this [here](https://gyazo.com/53661be38eab3421c73973d112687c85)
Does this look correct? should it be starting at -13dB? If so can I use this to calculate the cutoff frequency?

Answer (score 0):

The cut-off frequency is slightly below 5 kHz: -

[image]

That's the point where the output signal falls to the half power point i.e. 3 dB below the input signal. If you need a more accurate answer then do the math on the filter and find the half power point that way.

Comment: For Chebyshev filters (type I) the cut-off frequency is commonly defined in a different way. See my comment under Dave Tweed's answer.

Comment: See this for an explanation that both methods are valid (depending on the amount of pass band ripple: http://www.matheonics.com/Tutorials/Chebyshev.html#Paragraph_4.2 - go to the section entitled Natural cutoff frequency determination